# boolean not working on graphics java

Tags: java

Here is my code

```
package javaapplication7;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;``

import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

public class JavaApplication7 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    JButton j = new JButton();

    boolean drawHello = true;

    boolean drawWorld = false;

   String hello = "Hello";

   String World = "World";


   public JavaApplication7(){

       this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(j,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     boolean drawWorld = true;

      repaint();
}

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (drawHello)
             g.drawString(hello, 50, 50);

    if (drawWorld)
             g.drawString(World, 70, 70);
}



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        JavaApplication7 j7 = new JavaApplication7();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(250,250);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.add(j7);
    }

}
```

Comment: `drawHello` is `true` and `drawWorld` is `false`. So why shouldn´t the boolean work? you didn´t add the `ActionListener` to anything so you will never be able to set `drawWorld` to `true`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please define a precise question of what does not work exactly. Your question is like "there is an error!".

Comment: thanks for helping...sorry to trouble you because i was having big trouble on my main project and its my 1st time to ask

Comment: this is not the main project i have trouble with....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I don't understand that you've defined a `Boolean` and then you create another one in `actionPerformed()` just remove the `Boolean` as follows:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

drawWorld = true;

  repaint();
}
```

Because you allready created it there :

```
public class JavaApplication7 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

JButton j = new JButton();

boolean drawHello = true;

boolean drawWorld = false; //<------
```

Also add

```
j.addActionListener(this);
```

Like this :

```
public JavaApplication7(){

   this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   j.addActionListener(this);
   add(j,BorderLayout.NORTH);

}
```

Comment: thanks for helping...sorry to trouble you because i was having big trouble on my main project and its my 1st time to ask

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

  drawWorld = true;
  repaint();
}
```

If you re-declare it in your method, the global value will not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

you have two mistakes in your code.

The first one, you want to add the `ActionListener` to the `JButton`, otherwise you will never execute the `actionPerformed` method.(i simply guess you want the action to be performed on the button).

```
public JavaApplication7() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    add(j, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    j.addActionListener(this);
}
```

the second one is that you are using a local variable in the `actionPerformed` method, remove the type identifier there to assign the class variable. Otherwise you will only set the local variable `drawWorld` to true, which wont change the initial value of the class variable `drawWorld`. In this case the `paintComponent` wont notify the "change" you have done to the variable `darwWorld` because you never reassigned it as `true`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    drawWorld = true;
    repaint();
}
```